# Issue with MsgBox added under for loop

Tags: vba, loops, msgbox

I have the following code added under a function and also under for loop.

```
If Not setFcType(agt, ma, sma) Then
    fcComm1 = "Error"
    MsgBox "Entered Agt/Ma/Sma value is incorrrect", vbOKOnly
    Exit Function
End If
```

When i enter any values in excel, I get this code working able to observe the MsgBox, However It keeps on showing the MsgBox (even upon pressing OK) until the whole excel calculated all the cells (I have huge datas in my excel and lot of functions running behind).
Is there any way overcome this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

The only way that function is called and messagebox pops up is that setFcType is called during Excel Cells  calculations or directly from an event from VBA.

Search your whole VBA code(event handlers) and also all the Excel Sheets and try to find  setFcType  and remove those if needed.